# Laravel Breeze Authenticate middleware not redirecting when unauthenticated

Tags: laravel, laravel-9, laravel-breeze

I am using Laravel 9, extending Laravel Breeze for authentication.
I have routes that are protected by the auth middleware (`\App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php`), in which I've specified that `redirectTo()` should return `route('auth.login')`.
This was working great until a few days ago when suddenly all stopped! This was around the same time that I introduced Laravel Sanctum for API authentication.

When not logged in, and you try to access a protected route, [this 500 error](https://flareapp.io/share/v5pWKlD7#F42) pops up:

> Attempt to read property "headers" on bool at `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`:191

I have tried to debug this and found out that the issue is in the `unauthenticated()` method in Laravel's main `Authenticate.php` class. The redirection does not happen properly. When I extend this class in my app's `Authenticate.php`, I realise that the following works and I get a 404 error:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, array $guards)
{
    abort(404);
}
```

If, however, I do the following, I am back to the original error detailed in the aforementioned link:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, array $guards)
{
    return redirect(route('auth.login'));
}
```

I can't explain why this is the case. If I echo out the redirect, it also kind of works, but this is a hack.

Someone, please help explain what's going on.

Comment: The error (which should of course be included in the question) is pretty clear; at some point the method is passed a boolean instead of a response object. I'd put some debugging in at line 80 of `VerifyCsrfToken.php` and see what that closure is being passed.

Comment: Yes, I had already done this. The response is `true`. `$next($request)` returns true, and the next middleware is `Authenticate` - which is where I think the problem is.

Comment: Well if the closure is being passed `true` instead of a response, just work your way backwards through the code until you find the problem. Every middleware should call `$next($request)` so the request pipeline can continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more debugging, I found that the issue was indeed in the `Authenticate` middleware, and specifically in the `unauthenticated()` method.
This throws the `AuthenticationException` which in turn is hijacked by a custom Handler I had added as part of the Laravel sanctum that I introduced, and forgotten about, for API authentication.

The purpose of this handler was to override the default Laravel error message when an API request wasn't authenticated.

In there, I check if the request was to the `/api` route and then return the custom error message. If, however, it wasn't, I was returning `true`. This is the culprit.

```
$this->renderable(function (AuthenticationException $e, $request) {
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Not authorised.'], 401);
    }

    return true; //Bad
});
```

The correct way to do it (when I want Laravel to handle any other requests) is to simply return nothing.
[The docs say](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/errors#rendering-exceptions):

> If the closure given to the renderable method does not return a value, Laravel's default exception rendering will be utilized